# Captions: Write directly below "Figure"

Tags: captions

a typical caption below an image looks like:

> Fig 1.1: Whatever the content might be
>   ***_*__*_*__** it is described here.

My problem is that I'd like to write below "Fig 1.1" at the position of ***_*__*_*__**. I've managed to replace "Figure" by Fig, thus the lost space isn't that huge, but it's still annoying... Is there any way avaid this indent?
Maybe something with \noindent? But this would require inserting manual line breaks everywhere...

I can't provide a minimum working example since it would require an image however everyone should see the issue when writing a little caption of at least two lines below an image.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Comment: its \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}. Captions package is loaded this way: \usepackage[format=hang,
justification=RaggedLeft,
singlelinecheck=false,
figurename=Fig.,
aboveskip=7pt,
belowskip=0pt]{caption}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the caption indent to `0pt` using `\setcapindent`; a little example using some of you settings for caption (I suppressed `format=hang, justification=RaggedLeft`, since they are contradictory with your desired formatting):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false, figurename=Fig., aboveskip=7pt, belowskip=0pt]{caption}
\setcapindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\begin{figure}
\centering
A
\caption{Some text here to replace the actual caption for this figure. Add some more text to span several lines.}
\end{figure}
```

\end{document}

[image]

Comment: thanks, this looks promising and your working example does exactly what I was looking for :) However if I load the caption package with format=hang everything is back to how it was before. So what does format=Hang change? EDIT: Ah I see you changed your example :) In what way is format=hang contradictionary? What does it do exactly?

Comment: @Elarion using `format=hang` indents the caption text, so it will hang under the first line of the text, which is precisely what you don't want.

Comment: ah, okay so this was the issue. I copied that setting from some page without knowing what it does and since everything was fine before it wasn't an issue but then I noticed the indent and I like better without one :) Thanks a lot for your quick help!

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\usepackage[format=plain,
  justification=RaggedRight, 
  singlelinecheck=false, 
  figurename=Fig., 
  aboveskip=7pt, 
  belowskip=0pt]{caption}
```

instead of your setting.

Comment: this also does look nice, thank you :) Btw: is it possible to shift the entire caption to the right for lets say 10pt? Adding a \hspace{10pt} directly before \caption{} isn't working...

Comment: @Elarion Add `margin=10pt` to the `caption` package options. BTW: The `caption` package has a manual ;-)

Comment: hmm, somehow that doesn't change a thing... Although I do not get a warning or something similar. I've found the manual :) but I couldn't find a working way to change the margin in order to shift the caption right or left

Comment: @Elarion When I add `margin=10pt` to the example document from Gonzalo Medina answer, it will actually change the margin of the caption. So if this does not work for you we need an example document from you showing the problem. I'm sorry, but "I can't provide a minimum working example since it would require an image however everyone should see the issue when writing a little caption of at least two lines below an image." is neither true nor sufficient.